# Java: How to implement a queue system to play audioclips?

Tags: java, audio, queue

First question/post on here, hopefully I've done it right!

Using java, I need a method to somehow add audio files to a queue and play the next file once the last one has finished because at the minute they just play over the top of each other. I am using Audiosystem to play the sound files.

I thought of using an array to store the sound clips waiting to be played but got stumped and didn't know where to go from there.

Hopefully someone can help, thanks.

Comment: For now, you're not doing very good. Your question is very vague and general. You are not presenting any research or effort on your part, just asking for people to come up with complete solutions. But, you still might get an answer, there are quite a lot of karma whores around here.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class MidiPlayer{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
          Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
          if (sequencer == null)
              throw new MidiUnavailableException();
          sequencer.open();
          FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("music.mid");
          Sequence Seq = MidiSystem.getSequence(is);
          sequencer.setSequence(Seq);
          sequencer.start();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
here is a sample code that shows you how to play MIDI files in your java program, hope it helps
```